# how to compare state variables of 2 components in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've a component, whose state has a variables that stores a random value of 0-3, I have 2 of this in my app.js, now I want to compare the state of the this 2 components. please help.

this is my component.

```
import React from "react";

export default class player extends React.Component {
constructor(...args) {
super(...args);
this.state = {
  shoot: 0
};
}
shooter = () => {
this.setState({ shoot: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)) });
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.shoot}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => this.shooter()}>shoot it</button>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

this is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Player from "./player";

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
      <Player />
      <Player />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

How can I compare `state.shoot` in both `<Player />` ? I want to check if both the `state.shoot` are equal.

Comment: First thing shooter function needs manual binding in constructor or change it to arrow function. Your question isn’t clear to understand your expectation/issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting the state in the app component. this way you have more power on the data, for example :

App component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Player from "./player";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
super(...aan rgs);
this.state = {
    // create array of all your players
        players : [{shoot :0}, {shoot :0}]
    }
}
shooter = (id) => {
let players = this.state.player
/// maping the new players array
players.map(element, index => {
    if(id == index){
        element.shoot = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)
    }
}
this.setState({players) });
}

checkPlayers = () =>{
    // this is example... you can loop over your array and find what you need
    if(this.state.players[0].shoot == this.state.players[1].shoot){
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
    {this.state.players.map(i => {
        // pass the values to the player component (don't forget the id)
        return <Player shoot={i.shoot} shooter={this.shooter} id={i}/>
    }
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Player component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class player extends React.Component {

setShooter = () => {
    this.props.shooter(this.props.id)
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.props.shoot}</h1>
    <button onClick={this.setShooter}</button>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default player;
```